# Groovy way to conditionally append to a String

Tags: groovy, append

Good old java way to conditionally append something to string is as follows:

```
if (booleanFlag) {
    myString += "something to append"
}
```

Can I do the same in more groovy way, ideally in one line?

Comment: What you have in the question makes more sense then over simplifying it. Having in one line as Tim mentioned in comment would be `booleanFlag ? 'something to append' : ''` would work for it forces to use the `else` condition and I don't think that is reasonable/pragmatic programming. :) My 2¢. I would vote up your question as the best answer to the question.

Comment: @dmahapatro you are right, I don't see any much better solution below and that's why I haven't accepted any answer.  I was just curious whether Groovy has something specific for that problem, like there are elvis, spaceship operators etc. Ternary would be just Java style and as you noticed it forces to use `else`.

Comment: Groovy does have different approaches (all of the answers are examples of Groovy's flexibility) to this problem but you have to see which makes more sense and less bloat.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A very Groovy way to do this would be with GStrings:

```
"$myString${booleanFlag ? 'something to append' : ''}"
```

Comment: I know this answer is here for almost century.

I did not exactly understand it.

So for example I want to do in jenkins pipeline this:

echo "My text ${statemen ? 'more text' : 'almost'}" mean that if statemen is True then "more text" is added otherwise "almost" ?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a groovy way using [GString closures](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_special_case_of_interpolating_closure_expressions):

```
>>> def world = false
>>> def people = true
>>>
>>> def message = "Hello${sw -> if (world) sw << ' World'; if (people) sw << ' People'}"
>>>
>>> message
Hello People
>>>
>>> people = false
>>> world = true
>>>
>>> message
Hello World
>>>
>>> world = false
>>> message
Hello
```

The string looks kinda long and could do with some indentation, but groovy shell did not allow me to split the lines. Switched to an IDE, turns out you can write the string better like this (with the help of [triple quote strings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_triple_double_quoted_string)):

```
def message = 
"""Hello${sw -> 
    if (false) sw << ' World!'
    if (false) sw << ' People!'
    if (true)  sw << ' Groovy!'
}"""
```

Now that's groovy!

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
def b = true
def s = 's'

s += b ? 's' : ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution creating a `String.metaClass.when` method:

```
String.metaClass.when = { it ? delegate : '' }
```

Testing:

```
flag = true
myString = 'foo '
myString += "to append".when flag
assert myString == 'foo to append'

myString = 'foo ' + "to append".when(false)
assert myString == 'foo '
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this pattern is a good candidate for some meta-programming.

```
def myString = 'Hello'

use(StringBuilderCategory) {
    assert new StringBuilder(myString).append(true, 'World').toString() == 'HelloWorld'
    assert new StringBuilder(myString).append(false, 'World').toString() == 'Hello'
}

class StringBuilderCategory {
    static StringBuilder append(StringBuilder builder, boolean condition, String str) {
        if(condition) {
            builder.append(str)
        } else {
            builder
        }
    }
}
```

I used a `StringBuilder` to avoid implying that `String`s are mutable, but a similar method can be added to `String` to get it down to this:

```
use(TheCategory) {
    myString = myString.append(booleanFlag, 'something to append')
}
```

Of course there's the option of using the meta class instead of a category.

Comment: Isn't this over engineering for something simple as String concatenation? I am just thinking out loud in terms of pragmatic programming.

Comment: Well, it's actually *conditional* String concatenation. As for the over-engineering aspect, I think it depends on how often it's used. Groovy doesn't have an operator for this, so that leaves inline code or method calls as the only choices. There are plenty of answers demonstrating inline implementations, so I chose the latter. Personally, I'd use `booleanFlag ? 'something to append' : ''` or `if (booleanFlag) myString += "something to append"`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like one line to me:

```
if (booleanFlag) myString += "something to append";
```

Comment: This solution violates [IfStatementBraces](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-braces.html#IfStatementBraces) CodeNarc rule and is usually considered as bad practice also in Java

Comment: `myString += booleanFlag ? 'something to append' : ''` would also, work, but I prefer the first option (in the question), as ternaries can lead to a muddle

Comment: The OP explicitly asked about the groovy way. he obviously knew java and so this answer is useless